# Casting fails when deserializing JSON

Tags: json, typescript, serialization, types

**Please take into account that this question is about Typescript and not vanilla Javascript.**

I am trying to deserialize a very simple JSON string into a **Typescript** object and then casting into the correct type.

*After casting at `const obj = <FooClass>JSON.parse(s)` I would expect the `typeof` operator to return `FooClass`.* Why the operator still returns `object` ?

Why does casting here fails? How can I deserialize and still have access to `somefunc` ?

Example code:

```
class FooClass {
  public baz = 0
  public somefunc() {
    return this.baz * 2
  }
}

const jsonData = {
  baz: 1234,
}

test('deserialize example', () => {
  const s = JSON.stringify(jsonData)

  const obj = <FooClass>JSON.parse(s)     // Cast here
  console.log(typeof obj)                 // typeof still returns object

  console.log(obj)
  console.log(obj.somefunc())
})
```

Output:

```
  console.log
    object

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/deserialize.test.ts:15:11)

  console.log
    { baz: 1234 }

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/deserialize.test.ts:17:11)


TypeError: obj.somefunc is not a function
```

Comment: That's a runtime error, it has nothing to do with casting. `jsonData` doesn't have `somefunc` property, so I don't understand why you're surprised to get that error.

Comment: because I am deserializing and casting into a FooClass object. The function should be available! I was expecting `typeof obj` to be equal to `FooClass`

Comment: You'll need to use `Object.assign` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: Do you come from a strongly typed language? JS is weakly typed, there are no casts. `as` or `<type>` syntax variations are *type assertions* and do not do anything at runtime. Functions also do not survive serialization

Comment: This question is about typescript, not javascript.

Comment: @JuanLeni casting is (unsafely) assigning a type to a value. `const x: number = null as any` doesn't magically turn `null` into a number, as `<FooClass>JSON.parse(s)` doesn't magically make `somefunc` appear.

Comment: In my opinion @NadiaChibrikova was the most useful answer! Thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad it helped!

Comment: @JuanLeni - in the example you specified: "typeof still returns object". This is a runtime behaviour, `typeof` in TS has both runtime and compile-time meanings. The runtime one (the one used in `console.log(typeof object)` will return one of the predefined strings as per spec, you know that, right? In the case of objects, `"object"`. Methods not surviving serialization [unless you provide a custom `toJSON` method dealing with them] is also a runtime behaviour (which is wht `Object.assign` is used, there are also a couple of other solutions). And because of that the parsed object does not have

Comment: the method - this is purely a JavaScript problem, only the type *inference* and type *assertion* are related to TS here. And the "cast" (again, there are no casts in TS) will not do anything with the object - type and value spaces are separate.

Comment: TypeScript uses the term ["type assertion"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and not "cast", to try to prevent confusion about its effects.Type assertions *inform* the compiler that an expression will be of the asserted type. They do not *change* anything at runtime. It is a prediction ("the weather will be sunny tomorrow") and not a command ("make the sun shine tomorrow"). If you know that a value will not already be of the type you're asserting that it is, you are not casting it; you're just lying to the compiler by asserting a falsehood.

Answer (score 1):

In typescript you can cast `any` (return type of `JSON.parse`) to *anything*. The responsibility of ensuring if the casting is "correct", and the casted value indeed matches the type it's being casted to is **yours**.

**Casting is only telling the type checker how to treat that value from the point of casting.**

Turning that object to an instance of your class is also your responsibility. You could however do something like this:

```
type Foo = {
  baz: number
}

class FooClass {
  public baz: number = 0

  constructor(input: Foo) {
    this.baz = input.baz
  }

  public somefunc() {
    return this.baz * 2
  }
}

const rawFoo = JSON.parse(s) as Foo
const fooClassInstance = new FooClass(rawFoo)
// ready to be used as an instance of FooClass
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvAsAKClARgQwC8AuKAOwFcBbXCAJywF8ssBjAG3wGcvYEBhTjzRYcYCrnYBLVniKlKNesigAGFtiis4ZLsDoVWwOHQAUUsuOCl4cAJQjNOYAAspXAHQFCKi1a9EolDMmEHikjJQXHBUEABmFGSspg4YTlB0EMAUdGRQru4BPgBUUABMQSEhbDp6UABW0WQAIvjA%20CppON6kAIxlAMwALAA0TBrausBRKgBSAMoA8gByHnp0FgDmUnEgpo06re12ANwTtdN0%20ADutnNLq2D4dFwQplwO3HxwNVNQcQIhFwAJJTfBJaAoMgQa7fQTcLimK63BB2LAAenRGQg%20AAJiB8ohaFAKK9cVAvuCoBY9ODWNA4HE4UCgA)

Comment: This is acceptable though it requires a custom constructor. I was somehow expecting the casting to "apply" this copy. Any chance this "copy constructor" could be automatic?

Comment: @JuanLeni Think of this language as javascript with static typing and a few extras. It will compile (transpile) to js and the author's goal was to make the transpiled code easy to read and recognizeable on it's own. If you take my advice, don't try to treat this language as java/scala/cpp or any other strictly typed language you are coming from. Anything you learn about JS works in ts too.

Comment: TypeScript uses the term ["type assertion"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) and not "cast", to try to prevent confusion about its effects.Type assertions *inform* the compiler that an expression will be of the asserted type. They do not *change* anything at runtime. It is a prediction ("the weather will be sunny tomorrow") and not a command ("make the sun shine tomorrow"). If you know that a value will not already be of the type you're asserting that it is, you are not casting it; you're just lying to the compiler by asserting a falsehood.

Comment: @jcalz haha lying to the compiler, nice way to put it :D

Answer (score 0):

For completion, I copy here a solution that I find both efficient and clean:

```
test('casting fails example', () => {
  const s = JSON.stringify(jsonData)

  const obj = Object.assign(new FooClass(), JSON.parse(s))

  console.log(typeof obj)
  console.log(obj)
  console.log(obj.somefunc())
})
```

This could later be improved using generics

```
function deserializeJSON<T>(c: { new (): T }, s: string): T {
  return Object.assign(new c(), JSON.parse(s))
}

const obj = deserializeJSON(FooClass, s)
```